# not able to get full integer value while decoding json object to php array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I send a curl request on facebook api and i am getting this response.

```
'{
    "id": "137392510101234",
    "email": "open_mhfgkal_user@tfbnw.net",
    "first_name": "Open",
    "last_name": "User",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/137392510108522/",
    "name": "Open Graph Test User"
}'
```

Now i am trying to read the value of id. I used below code for it.

```
$jsonid='{
    "id": "137392510101234",
    "email": "open_mhfgkal_user@tfbnw.net",
    "first_name": "Open",
    "last_name": "User",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/137392510108522/",
    "name": "Open Graph Test User"
}';

 $jsonArrayToken = json_decode($jsonid,true);
 echo $jsonArrayToken['id'];
```

But i cant read the whole value of id. 
i am getting only first four digits "1373".
i want whole id "137392510101234".

Is there any mistake? please suggest me.

Comment: You example code works fine so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: i get the good value when i tested your code, do you convert the value somewhere later?

Comment: Set the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option in `json_decode` - that will make it parse all large integers that might overflow the system’s integer limit into string values, so that there’s no problems with loss of precision due to implicit conversion to a float value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your code added var_export, no problem found.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain');
$jsonid='{
    "id": "137392510108522",
    "email": "open_mhfgkal_user@tfbnw.net",
    "first_name": "Open",
    "last_name": "User",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/137392510108522/",
    "name": "Open Graph Test User"
}';

 $jsonArrayToken = json_decode($jsonid,true);
 echo $jsonArrayToken['id'] . "\n\n";
 var_export($jsonArrayToken);

?>
```

### Response:

```
137392510108522

array (
  'id' => '137392510108522',
  'email' => 'open_mhfgkal_user@tfbnw.net',
  'first_name' => 'Open',
  'last_name' => 'User',
  'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/137392510108522/',
  'name' => 'Open Graph Test User',
)
```

---

Comment: it works for me.Thank you so much you saved my time i was stucked in this from last 8 hours.Thanks again. You are amazing man.

Answer (score 0):

working fine check here:

eval link :

https://eval.in/734713

May be problem is some where else not in this code

Answer (score -1):

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) provides an object, not an array. You should access the data like following :

```
<?php
    $jsonid='{
        "id": "137392510108522",
        "email": "open_mhfgkal_user@tfbnw.net",
        "first_name": "Open",
        "last_name": "User",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/137392510108522/",
        "name": "Open Graph Test User"
    }';

    $arrayid = json_decode($jsonid); // json_decode provide an OBJECT, not an array
    $id = $arrayid->id;

    echo $id;
?>
```